# FFT - Calculating exact frequency between frequency bins

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I am using [a nice FFT library I found online](http://www.corix.dk/Mix-FFT/mix-fft.html) to see if I can write a pitch-detection program. So far, I have been able to successfully let the library do FFT calculation on a test audio signal containing a few sine waves including one at 440Hz (I'm using 16384 samples as the size and the sample rate at 44100Hz).

The FFT output looks like:

```
433.356Hz - Real: 590.644 - Imag: -27.9856 - MAG: 16529.5
436.047Hz - Real: 683.921 - Imag: 51.2798 - MAG: 35071.4
438.739Hz - Real: 4615.24 - Imag: 1170.8 - MAG: 5.40352e+006
441.431Hz - Real: -3861.97 - Imag: 2111.13 - MAG: 8.15315e+006
444.122Hz - Real: -653.75 - Imag: 341.107 - MAG: 222999
446.814Hz - Real: -564.629 - Imag: 186.592 - MAG: 105355
```

As you can see, the 441.431Hz and 438.739Hz bins both show equally high magnitude outputs (the right-most numbers following "MAG:"), so it's obvious that the target frequency 440Hz falls somewhere between. Increasing the resolution might be one way to close in, but that would add to the calculation time.

How do I calculate the exact frequency that falls between two frequency bins?

**UPDATE:**

I tried out [Barry Quinn's "Second Estimator"](http://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-fft-peak) discussed on the DSPGuru website and got excellent results. The following shows the result for 440Hz square wave - now I'm only off by 0.003Hz!

[image: FFT frequency estimation success]

Here is [the code I used](https://gist.github.com/hiromorozumi/f74fd4d5592a7f79028560cb2922d05f). I simply adapted [this example](https://github.com/vadymmarkov/Beethoven/blob/master/Source/Estimation/Strategies/QuinnsSecondEstimator.swift) I found, which was for Swift. Thank you everyone for your very valuable input, this has been a great learning journey :)

Comment: The methods you are looking for are called DESA (discrete energy separation algorithm).

Comment: Thank you for your tip, I will look into this. I also found [this post](http://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-fft-peak) showing several solutions...

Comment: I’d expect the most computationally-*inexpensive* and most reliable method is oversampling the FFT (i.e., zero-padding the input, especially to some power-of-two). But here are a few other techniques you can look at: https://gist.github.com/fasiha/957035272009eb1c9eb370936a6af2eb

Comment: I did wonder if I could take advantage of the harmonic content to help with the estimation. I'll definitely explore these Harmonic Product Spectrum techniques more. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Sinc interpolation can be used to accurately interpolate (or reconstruct) the spectrum between FFT result bins.  A zero-padded FFT will produce a similar interpolated spectrum.  You can use a high quality interpolator (such as a windowed Sinc kernel) with successive approximation to estimate the actual spectral peak to whatever resolution the S/N allows.  This reconstruction might not work near the DC or Fs/2 FFT result bins unless you include the effects of the the spectrum's conjugate image in the interpolation kernel.

See: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/Interpolation/Ideal_Bandlimited_Sinc_Interpolation.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker%E2%80%93Shannon_interpolation_formula for details about time domain reconstruction, but the same interpolation method works in either domain, frequency or time, for bandlimited or time limited signals respectively.

If you require a less accurate estimator with far less computational overhead, parabolic interpolation (and other similar curve fitting estimators) might work.  See: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Quadratic_Interpolation_Spectral_Peaks.html and https://mgasior.web.cern.ch/mgasior/pap/FFT_resol_note.pdf for details for parabolic, and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.555.2873&rep=rep1&type=pdf for other curve fitting peak estimators.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me on all these different interpolation techniques. I did try quadratic and other easier interpolations following [this page](http://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-interpolate-fft-peak) and got improvements but I am still missing targets by up to about 0.5Hz. So I guess I'll have to buckle down for some more reading on Sinc Interpolation and windowed-sinc filters :)

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the "true" frequency, once I used *[parabola fit algorithm](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/parshl/Peak_Detection_Steps_3.html)*. It worked very well for my use case.

This is the way I followed in order to find the fundamental frequency:

- Calculate DFT ([WOLA](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Overlap_Add_OLA_STFT_Processing.html)).
- Find peaks in your DFT bins.
- Find Harmonic Product Spectrum. Not the most reliable nor precise, but this is a very easy way of finding your fundamental frequency candidates.
- Based on peaks and HPS, use parabola fit algorithm to find fundamental pitch frequency (and amplitude if needed).

For example, HPS says the fundamental (strongest) pitch is concentrated in bin `x` of your DFT; if bin `x` belongs to the peak `y`, then parabola fit frequency is taken from the peak `y` and that is the pitch you were looking for.

If you are not looking for fundamental pitch, but exact frequency in *any* bin, just apply parabola fit for that bin.

Some code to get you started:

```
struct Peak
{
    float         freq     ; // Peak frequency calculated by parabola fit algorithm. 
    float         amplitude; // True amplitude.   
    float         strength ; // Peak strength when compared to neighbouring bins.         
    uint16_t      startPos ; // Peak starting position (DFT bin).
    uint16_t      maxPos   ; // Peak location (DFT bin).
    uint16_t      stopPos  ; // Peak stop position (DFT bin).
}; 

void calculateTrueFrequency( Peak & peak, float const bins, uint32_t const fs, DFT_Magnitudes mags )
{
    // Parabola fit:
    float a = mags[ peak.maxPos - 1 ];
    float b = mags[ peak.maxPos     ];
    float c = mags[ peak.maxPos + 1 ];

    float p   = 0.5f * ( a - c ) / ( a - 2.0f * b + c );
    float bin = convert<float>( peak.maxPos ) + p;

    peak.freq      = convert<float>( fs ) * bin / bins / 2;
    peak.amplitude = b - 0.25f * ( a - c ) * p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I'm guessing that this is also called the quadratic method? The formula for amplitude will come in handy, also. With audio signal, the largest magnitude most often seems to end up being the fundamental, but I'll see if using HPS can help even more.

Comment: Regarding "largest amplitude", it's much more than that. I'd definitely implement HPS because it is not complicated. Good luck.

Comment: I think there is an error in the last line of code: it should be "0.25f * (...)" not "0.25f + (...)" according to the source linked in the first sentence.

Comment: @HL65536 Indeed! Fixed, thanks.